# Incorrect directory structure created using jfrog CLI

Tags: artifactory, bintray, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray, jfrog-mission-control

I am trying to download the entire folder (as it is with all files and subfolders) from an Artifactory repo to my local folder.

Note - I am using Artifactory Pro cloud version

This how my Artifactory local repo (generic) looks like -

[image]

I run the following command in jfrog CLI (used [this](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go/issues/176) article as refrence) -

```
jfrog rt download --include-dirs=true --flat=true --user=XXX --password=XXX --url=https://XXXX.jfrog.io/XXXX --recursive '/support-pack/aem-dispatcher/files/(*)' '{1}'
```

The files get downloaded however it results in a weird folder structure -

[image]

Below is a screenshot of the logs

[image]

Notice the additional `resume` folder under the `resume` folder. Why is this happening? 
I want the exact structure under `files` folder in Artifactory to be replicated in my local folder.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The answer turned out to be much simpler than expected. All I had to do was get rid of `--include-dirs=true` in my command.
Read [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles) article for more info.